# Convert NSDictionary To JSON

Tags: iphone, ios7

**How to Convert NSDictionary into JSON ?**

I have posted a dictionary into server using json. And in the time receiving the data from the server using GET method. the data cant be accessed using normal key calling method like

```
_secretanswer.text=[[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"%@",[customfield objectForKey:@"secanswer"]];
```

the server returning a NCFString as the result.

How to convert and post a NSDictionary in the JSON format?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSError * error;
NSData * jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:myDictionary options:0 error:&error]; 

NSString * myString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:jsonData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
```

Comment: It seems clear that OP was explicitly looking for a NSDictionary from his JSON data, not a NSString.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that what you're looking for is NSJSONSerialization.

This answer assumes use of NSURLConnection's block based API to execute your GET.

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:req queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
    if (data) {
        NSError *jsonError = nil;
        NSDictionary *dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&jsonError];
        if (dict) {
            // You got a valid NSDictionary out of your JSON response.
            NSLog(@"my returned dictionary: %@", dict);
        } else if (jsonError) {
            // JSON data could not be parsed into NSDictionary. Handle as appropriate for your application.
            return;
        }
    } else if (connectionError) {
        // Handle connection error
    }
}];
```

But even if you're using dataWithContentsOfURL:, the point is the same. Feed your data in to NSJSONSerialization's + jsonObjectWithData:options:error: method, check if you get a dictionary back from that, and proceed.

EDIT: If you're looking to create a JSON post body for an HTTP request from an NSDictionary, NSJSONSerialization has you covered there as well.

```
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:someDictionary options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
if (data) {
    // You got your data.
    NSLog(@"my data: %@", data);
    [someURLRequest setHTTPBody:data];
} else if (error) {
    NSLog(@"error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
}
```

Comment: @HotLicks Thanks for that. The answer has been updated.

Comment: You made a common mistake in your added error handling. see https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/an-nserror-error/ https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/ErrorHandling/ErrorHandling.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH9-SW5

Comment: Specifically, never test `error` to see if a call failed. There's always a returned value that indicates failure, and then and only then should one consult `error` to see what the error was. Also, in some odd cases, `error` can be nil even on failure. Instead of `if (!error)` it should be `if (data)`.

Comment: @smallduck I've edited the answer again. I believe the latest edits address the point you raise. Thanks for that feedback.