# Compress NSDictionary in JSON format

Tags: objective-c, json, xcode, compression, nsdictionary

How can i compress my `NSDictionary` object which is in JSON format? Do demonstrate, my current object is like that:

[image: noncompressed version]

And i want to make it be like that:

[image: compressed version]

Can you help me about that? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert NSDictionary To JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27293760/convert-nsdictionary-to-json)

Comment: No it is not, my NSDictionary is a valid JSON, i checked by using `isValidJSONObject` method. Thus, i do not have any problem with converting to json. What i'm trying to do is make it space free.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you want to remove all the whitespaces, try this:

```
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:dic options:0 error:nil];
NSString *jsonString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
jsonString = [jsonString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\s"
              withString:@""
              options:NSRegularExpressionSearch
              range:NSMakeRange(0, [jsonString length])];
```

Comment: Exactly, this is what i want, i'll try your solution, thanks.

Comment: @DilaraAlbayrak Don't forget to accept the answer if it worked ;)